# SQL - Filter a query result with an additional condition

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, conditional-statements

I have a database with two tables:
 - Credit which records all the payments that I have to receive
 - Payment which records the payments that I have received

The structure is
Credit: id, total
Payment: id, received

My goal is to have a query that print all the payments which are still not fully paid. For now I wrote a query which successfully prints 
- id of the credit
- total money request
- total money received
I just need to add a condition: don't print the records where the payment is fully done. This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT Credit.id,
       Credit.total,
       (SELECT SUM(Payment.received)
       FROM Payment WHERE Payment.id = Credit.id) AS TotalReceived
FROM Credit
WHERE Credit.total > 0;
```

I tried changing last row with "WHERE Credit.total > TotalReceived" but it doesn't work.

May you help me please? :)

PS. In the Credit the id is unique while in Payment table can be present many rows with the same id.

Comment: use joins and try to avoid co-related inner queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should get you the credit records that have not been paid.  your payment table should probably have a `creditId` field to join to instead of on `Credit.id = Payment.id` but if that's how it's set up this should work.

```
SELECT  c.id,
        c.total,
        SUM(Nz(p.received,0)) AS totalreceived
FROM    Credit c
        LEFT JOIN Payment p ON c.id = p.id --not sure about this?
WHERE   c.total > 0
GROUP BY c.id, c.total
HAVING  c.total > SUM(Nz(p.received,0))
```

Comment: Almost: I edited your JOIN in LEFT JOIN but however I can't see the Credit's row for which there is no one Payment's record.

Comment: did the left join help?

Comment: @pittuzzo.. with nulls you need to coalesce the null to 0 for sum to work.. try the update

Comment: Yes! I have to use the LEFT JOING for what I need but the point is that the last code's row
HAVING c.total > SUM(Bonifici.importo)
correctly remove the records for which the payments cover fully the credit
BUT it also remove those credits which haven't any payment yet...

And if I use "HAVING  c.total > SUM(ISNULL(p.received,0))" it's not compiling: arguments error...

Comment: you are using access?

Comment: Yes I'm using ACCESS 2010...
I tried:
 IIF(ISNULL(p.received),0,p.received)
But it is not working.... still code error

Comment: i think Nz is the ISNULL equivalent in access.. try that

Comment: ok... I forgot the SUM... Now it is working! Thanks so much @JamieD77
Solution is your code but with this last row:
`HAVING  c.total > IIF(ISNULL(SUM(p.received)),0,SUM(p.received))`

Comment: And yes `HAVING c.total > NZ(SUM(p.received),0)`
is working!

Answer (score 3):

You can't add a `WHERE` clause for an aggregated column unless you use SubQueries.  You have to use a combination of `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

Your query can be rewritten like this (I prefer this structure using a JOIN rather than use a co-related query like you have used.

```
SELECT Credit.id, Sum (Credit.total), SUM(Payment.received) TotalReceived
FROM Credit
INNER JOIN Payment ON Payment.id = Credit.id
WHERE Credit.total > 0
GROUP BY Credit.id
```

Now, add a `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT Credit.id, Sum (Credit.total), SUM(Payment.received) TotalReceived
FROM Credit
INNER JOIN Payment ON Payment.id = Credit.id
WHERE Credit.total > 0
GROUP BY Credit.id
HAVING SUM(Payment.received) > 0
```

If you absolutely want to retain your structure, use a subquery like this

```
Select Id, Total, TotalReceived
From
(
    SELECT Credit.id, Credit.total, (SELECT SUM(Payment.received)
    FROM Payment WHERE Payment.id = Credit.id) AS TotalReceived
    FROM Credit
    WHERE Credit.total > 0
) DerivedTable
Where TotalReceived > 0
```

Comment: Well I tried a code that I wrote using the INNER JOIN but ACCESS is giving me errors like this:
"You can not execute a query that does not include the term "id" specified as part of an aggregate function." I had the same with your code... However I think your code is not doing exaclty what I need :)